# How can I program my self made Arduino board using USB to TTL converter?

Tags: serial, atmega328

Recently I got a coupon for JLCPCB which was 100% discount so, I designed my 10 Arduino board specially for my needs and ordered it from JLC PCB. The schematic of the board is given. [image: HERE] At the time while I was designing the board I  thought of using USB to TTL converter which I have one having RX, TX, VCC and GND pins. So, I forgot to add pinouts for MISO which was D13 and also D12. So, how can I program my board now with that USB to TTL converter?

Describing about my board, it has a separate pinout for programming which has pins like GND, VCC, TX and RX. I tried but couldn't upload the program. Please help me out.

Forgot to mention, it uses ATMEGA328P-AU.

Comment: Without the ICSP pins you won't be able to program a bootloader into the board. You will have to bodge in some wires to those pins to connect it to a programmer / other Arduino to program the bootloader. Also your LEDs aren't wired right. You need a resistor for each LED, not just one resistor for the whole set.

Comment: @Majenko I think you looked for LED5, It is a RGB LED with common positive termianl. So, I used only one resistor.

Comment: @Majenko Can't I program using USB to TTL converter? I watched this video and designed my board. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNIMCdVOHOM . He didn't use those ICSP pins.

Comment: Yes, it's an RGB common anode. You need one resistor for each LED. Not one for the common. Ask yourself: what's the forward voltage of "the" LED? And what happens if multiple LEDs are on at once?

Comment: You can only program through UART if you have a bootloader. The chip doesn't know how to understand UART data by itself. Only once the bootloader is on there will your UART interface do anything at all.

Comment: @Majenko Oh, Yes. I forgot about that and neglected this thing. But can you suggest me any way of programming it?

Comment: Like I said: solder in some bodge wires to the pins you need. You'll need a steady hand and some thin wires (I use 30 AWG wire-wrap wire with a high temperature PTFE insulation).

Comment: Alternatively you would need to program the MCU with the bootloader before soldering it to the board. Either by first soldering it to some other breakout board with the pins you need, or using a TQFP ZIF socket on a breakout board (although those are expensive).

Comment: @Majenko Ok. I will do that. Are other components placed right?

Comment: Looks reasonable - apart from those RGB LEDs...

Comment: @Majenko Will it have any problem if a resistor is connected to MISO pinout of atmega328p? Should I remove the resistor or without removing I can upload the bootloader? It is of 200 ohms

Comment: It should be fine. And D13 is SCK not MISO.

Comment: Your schematic doesn't have any bypass capacitors. Not on the ATMega, or the voltage regulators. And D1 is the wrong way around.

Comment: At the Arduino Website is a [tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone) for making an Arduino on a breadbord.